# How to highlight your html tags?

Tags: html

how to highlight my html tags? for instance: `<header>` or `<div class="header">` ? `<aside>` or `<div class="sidebar">` ?  Does browser feels the name of the tags? or it doesn't matter and its up to me? I really can't understand the importance of it

Comment: This needs a lot more detail to become answerable. Can you clarify what you mean by "highlight"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `header` and `aside` is HTML5 elements in comparison with `div`, which is from earlier HTML versions, and you can use either. Google HTML5 elements to learn more about their difference and why/how to use them

Comment: not exactly highlight. i start to build my html body. is that important to put as a name for my tag < header>, <footer>, <section> or I can name my tags as i wish just like as folowing <div class="header"> , <div class="footer"> <div class="MainContent">

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would want to use the tags like `<header>` instead of just the div and then an ID because it would less confusing to other programmers reading your code.

Comment: So, I would you <header> and ID only for programmers ? for codes to be more readable for them ? :)

Comment: Yes, if you are working by your self then it is up to you on what you to use, but if you are in a group then I would use the <header>

Comment: But theoretically, browser won't make any error alerts . right? both type of use are correct?

Comment: Yes. The browser interprets the same